# How to copy files across computers using SSH and MAC OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, unix, file, terminal, copying

I'm trying to copy my .profile, .rvm and .ssh folders/files to a new computer and keep getting a "not a regular file" response. I know how to use the `cp` and `ssh` commands but I'm not sure how to use them in order to transfer files from one computer to another.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: though you have recv'd answers, may I still recommend superuser.com?

Answer (score 480, accepted):

You can do this with the `scp` command, which uses the ssh protocol to copy files across machines. It extends the syntax of `cp` to allow references to other systems:

```
scp username1@hostname1:/path/to/file username2@hostname2:/path/to/other/file
```

Copy something from this machine to some other machine:

```
scp /path/to/local/file username@hostname:/path/to/remote/file
```

Copy something from another machine to this machine:

```
scp username@hostname:/path/to/remote/file /path/to/local/file
```

Copy with a port number specified:

```
scp -P 1234 username@hostname:/path/to/remote/file /path/to/local/file
```

Comment: I think that OP's use of the phrase 'how to use them in order to transfer' might be rewritten as 'how to use them to transfer'.  Wordy perhaps, but not terrifically wrong.

Comment: @High: ah indeed. :) *gets more coffee*

Comment: Thanks @Ether, but unfortunately, I keep getting a "not a regular file" response for directories that start with '.' like the .rvm folder im trying to transfer, any tips?

Comment: don't worry about it. I got it! I need to use -r  (r for recursive) in order to bring in whole directory structures. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, you can use `-r` for recursive, or just zip up the files and target the zip.

Comment: Last command with port must be: scp -P 1234 /path/to/local/file username@hostname:/path/to/remote/file

Answer (score 15):

First zip or gzip the folders:
Use the following command:

> zip -r NameYouWantForZipFile.zip foldertozip/

or

> tar -pvczf BackUpDirectory.tar.gz /path/to/directory

for gzip compression use SCP:

> scp username@yourserver.com:~/serverpath/public_html ~/Desktop

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look at rsync if you're doing a lot of files.

If you're going to making a lot of changes and want to keep your directories and files in sync, you may want to use a version control system like Subversion or Git.  See http://xoa.petdance.com/How_to:_Keep_your_home_directory_in_Subversion

Comment: Thanks @Andy, we are using SVN here at work but I just got a new computer and wanted to learn how to do everything through the command line since the guys prefer that here. I'm learning to love it as well :)