# bash command to copy file from one computer to another

Tags: macos, bash, unix, cp

Wasn't quite sure how to word this but let's say I've used `ssh` to remote into my friends MacBook (macbook_b) from my MacBook (macbook_a).

What command would I use to copy a file/directory to my MacBook (macbook_a) from my friends MacBook (macbook_b)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use scp (Secure Copy).

To copy FROM your machine to friends:

```
scp file_to_copy user@remote.server.fi:/path/to/location
```

In another direction:

```
scp user@remote.server.fi:/path/locatio/file_name file_name
```

If you need to copy an entire directory, you'll need to use the recursive flag, like this:

```
scp -r directory_to_copy user@remote.server.fi:/path/to/location
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're logged in on macbook_b:

```
scp file_to_copy username@macbook_a:/path/to/destination
```

or if you're logged in on macbook_a:

```
scp username@macbook_b:/path/to/file_to_copy local_destination
```

Comment: I keep getting "cp: username@computerName is not a directory" error. Do you know what causes this? I am using 'scp' as well, not 'cp'.

Comment: @MorganR: it looks like that for some reason the "cp"-command gets executed instead of "scp". Maybe you have an alias for "scp" that points to "cp", or maybe the "scp"-command is replaced by "cp"?

Comment: I missed out the ":" when referencing where I want the file to be copied. Always something simple. Thank you for your help, Terke Mikal.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/345347/how-to-copy-a-file-between-two-linux-machines) would help you with the answer you are looking for. In this you can use  scp ssh source destination example for your scenario you have requested for.

Also refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710946/copying-files-across-computers-using-ssh-and-mac-os-x-terminal) which has been already answered. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

first do pwd to get the path to the file of your friends macbook then

go into your machine's ssh window and do

scp user_name@machine_name(of your friend's):(copy the path after executing pwd)/file_name .(dot means your your current directory)

enter his password !

voila !!!